# precomputing some code in a scala closure.

Tags: scala, closures

In scala, I have the following code:

```
def isDifferentGroup(artifact2: DefaultArtifact) = getArtifact(artifact1Id).getGroupId != artifact2.getGroupId
val artifacts = getArtifacts().filter(isSameGroup)
```

the function `isDifferentGroup` is accessing the external String variable `artifactId` (closure).

I'd like to avoid computing `getArtifact(artifactId)` for each item in the list.

I could do as follows:

```
val artifact1: DefaultArtifact = getArtifact(artifact1Id)
def isDifferentGroup(artifact2: DefaultArtifact) = artifact1.getGroupId != artifact2.getGroupId
val artifacts = getArtifacts().filter(isSameGroup)
```

however, we are creating a variable `artifact1` outside the fonction `isDifferentGroup`, and that is ugly, because this variable is used only inside the fonction `isDifferentGroup`.

how to solve it?

one possibility would be to make a partial function as follows:

```
def isDifferentGroup(artifact1: DefaultArtifact)(artifact2: DefaultArtifact) = artifact1.getGroupId != artifact2.getGroupId
val artifacts = getArtifacts().filter(isDifferentGroup(getArtifact(artifact1Id)))
```

however, I have to move the code `getArtifact(artifactId)` outside the `isDifferentGroup` function, and I don't want this.

how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that is processed in a function body is evaluated every time the function is called, so you can't tell that a part of it will be statically evaluated and shared (without resorting to using some kind of external cache). So you have to separate the function body from values you want to evaluate in advance and use inside the function.

However, you can enclose such values in a block so that forms a compact block. The best thing I can think of is to declare a `val` with a function type, such as

```
val isDifferentGroup: DefaultArtifact => Boolean = {
    val gid = getArtifact(artifact1Id).getGroupId
    (artifact2: DefaultArtifact) => {
        (gid != artifact2.getGroupId)
    }
}
```

This way, you can explicitly state what part is evaluated statically only once in the main `val` block (here `gid`) and what part is evaluated in response to an `artifact2` argument. And you can call `isDifferentGroup` just as if it were a method:

```
println(isDifferentGroup(someArtifact))
```

This is basically just a different way of creating an encapsulating class like

```
val isDifferentGroup: DefaultArtifact => Boolean =
  new Function1[DefaultArtifact,Boolean] {
    val gid = getArtifact(artifact1Id).getGroupId

    override def apply(artifact2: DefaultArtifact): Boolean =
        (gid != artifact2.getGroupId);
  }
```

You can even declare it as a `lazy val`, in which case `gid` is evalauted *at most* once, the first time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a class to encapsulate both a (private) value and functionality?

This code will probably not compile, just to illustrate it:

```
class Artifact(artifact1Id: Id) {
  private val artifact1: DefaultArtifact = getArtifact(artifact1Id)

  def isDifferentGroup(artifact2: DefaultArtifact) = 
    artifact1.getGroupId != artifact2.getGroupId
}
```